# Android Studio Visual xml Editor not working

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The visual xml editor in Android Studio is not working, it only displays all grey with the text "android...CoordinatorLayout" on top of it. I had this happen before and fixed it by adding "Base." to the `parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` in styles.xml. However, this time it didn't fix my problem. Also, the preview/ visual editor isn't working in all my older projects too. I haven't opened AS for a few months now, so I suppose there has been an update or something as my usual fix doesn't seem to work anymore.

What I've tried:

1. Adding "Base."
2. Changing the theme, which only made the top Navigation Bar visible and nothing else.
3. Restarting.
4. Creating new projects and activities
5. changing the build gradle which messed everything up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. check android studio updates
2. do invalidate caches and restart

   3. or check the missing is there missing library of design

Comment: hm... i was thinking about updating, but i dont know how?

Comment: if you android studio is open then click on top right HELP and at the last you can see check updates OR  go for configure and see the option for check updates

Comment: alright, thanks. Ill try this tomorrow and give an update. Thanks for answering!

Comment: thanks, I updated Android Studio and it fixed the problem, thanks so much!